# Which is the best password hashing algorithm for PHP?

Tags: php, security, hash

I was just reading a [**post**](http://tinsology.net/2009/06/creating-a-secure-login-system-the-right-way/) to create a login system and while reading I saw about password hashing.

> We are going to store an sha256 hash which is a string always
> containing 64 characters.

This article is teaching to use **sha256** hash function. After reading this, I did not stop and started to search more about creating secure login system and then I came up with this article by [**wikiHow**](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL). In this article, they are using **sha512** hash function. This really confused me that which function am I going to use for my next login system. I still searched google for better article and found this article by [**crackstation**](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm). The writer recommends both sha256 and sha512.

> Only cryptographic hash functions may be used to implement password
> hashing. Hash functions like SHA256, SHA512, RipeMD, and WHIRLPOOL are
> cryptographic hash functions.

I thought my search is over and I can use `sha256` or `sha512` function but while searching more I found this [**SO Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords). The accepted answer by [**Robert K**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24950/robert-k) had new things for me. The things about I have never heard before which is **bcrypt** and **scrypt**.

All this stuff was written about 2 to 4 years ago.

**Question**

Which is the best password hashing algorithm used these days for PHP?

Comment: i think using more than 1 variables. For example: `sha1($username . '-' . $password);`

Comment: @userNOID: That's still not enough. You should read the linked question as well.

Comment: Also see Openwall's [Portable PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main thing here is that you want to choose a hash that is *slow*. The only feasible attack vector for any of these hashes is *brute forcing*. Meaning, an attacker can only try all possible passwords one after the other, hashing them using the same algorithm as you did and compare them to the hash. The longer this takes for one password the more infeasible it is to find a match.

The SHA family of algorithms is designed to be fast, because they're not designed to be used for this purpose. As such they are by themselves somewhat unsuitable for password hashing; though they can be used as part of an algorithm which makes them suitable, such as [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) (which in short repeats the hashing many thousands of times to *stretch* it).

bcrypt and scrypt are explicitly *designed to be slow* and are as such much more suitable for password hashing. bcrypt is designed to be very expensive in terms of CPU power, while scrypt is designed to be very expensive in terms of memory consumption. CPU power is better scalable using todays hardware than memory is, so scrypt is currently seen as the best thing to use. Though it is very cutting edge at the moment and has seen little support in terms of usable code. bcrypt on the other hand is supported by PHP using [`password_hash`](http://php.net/password_hash) directly.

Comment: Why answer this when there's a perfectly good canonical ***exact*** duplicate?

Comment: Why not? This question is explicitly about the differences between SHA* and *crypt, so a concise answer to this question isn't bad, no?

Comment: His question is: "Which is the best password hashing algorithm used these days for PHP?", which is perfectly answered in the duplicate. There's nothing here asking about the differences between SHA and crypt...

Comment: Alright, yes, the other answer is great. It is pretty lengthy though, so I still see value in a concise, simple answer specifically about what the difference between algorithms is and why some are better than others.

Comment: @deceze OK, you got a good little explaination but do you have a nice article to read more about `bcrypt` and `scrypt` ?

Comment: @Muhammad Not really. But blowfish (bcrypt) is sufficiently talked about in many places, Google should suffice. For scrypt I found this cute explanation: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gICktQu1ySU

Comment: @deceze I have youtube blocked here but I will figure that out with proxy. Thanks, I have your article about encodings to read. ;)

Comment: Hey, @deceze If bcrypt takes CPU power then what will happen to the hacker's system who is using brute-force attack?

Comment: @Muhammad What do you mean? It will make his CPU very busy for a long time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36604/discussion-between-muhammad-talha-akbar-and-deceze)