# PHP / MYSQLI Login Script

Tags: php, mysqli, md5

So far i have used a self written script in php using md5 hash to create the login and everything around it. I was wondering if there are some more secure alternatives i could implement in php today? What would you recomment?

Comment: *"I was wondering if there are some more secure alternatives i could implement in php today?"* - MD5 is well over 30 "years" old and a LOT of water's gone under the bridge since then. Use `password_hash()`. You also could have easily Google'd this.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547954/which-is-the-best-password-hashing-algorithm-for-php) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords), and finally, [more info here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=php+recommended+password+hashing).